# Add a filter function on laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, builder

I am getting some data from a model like:

```
public function getExternalCodes()
{
    return ExternalService::get()->pluck('add_id')->toArray();
}
```

Now before this I want to apply a function to filter the data by date:

```
public function getExternalCodes()
{
    $query =  ExternalService::get()->pluck('add_id')->toArray();

    return $query->filterByDate($query, new ExternalServce);
}
```

My filter by date function

```
private function filterByDate(Builder $query, Model $model)
    {

        if (!request()->has('interval')) {

            return $query;
        }

        $period = json_decode(request()->get('interval'));

        if ($period->from) {

            $query->where("{$model->getTable()}.created_at", ">=", Carbon::parse($period->from)->startOfDay());
        }

        if ($period->to) {

            $query->where("{$model->getTable()}.created_at", "<=", Carbon::parse($period->to)->endOfDay());
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

However I can not do it right now since I am calling `get()` before applying the filter. Any idea how to go about it ?

And yes dont add a question to filter with where since I can not do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Eloquent models, use [a local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) for that:

```
private function scopeFilterByDate($query)
{
    ....
}
```

Then use the scope with:

```
public function getExternalCodes()
{
    return ExternalService::filterByDate()->pluck('add_id')->toArray();
}
```

Comment: the issue with that is that this filter is on repositories and its being used with 10 different other models. So I cant do that

Comment: @PrStandup put it into a trait or create a base model class.

Comment: hmm do you think is okay to place it on base eloquent model ?

Comment: @PrStandup I mean create some kind of base model class which extends `Model`. I would use trait.

Comment: By the way, does `pluck()` performs a `get()` behind the scenes ?

Comment: @PrStandup yes it does.